# Mystic Island Math - Can you Figure it out?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers, alphametic

On Mystic Island math is done via symbols.

Distinct symbols represent distinct digits, varying from 0 to 9.

From the picture below, figure out the corresponding digits. Please provide your reasoning.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, for users attempting to answer this question, `$\Delta$` generates $\Delta$, `$\cap$` generates $\cap$, `$\cup$` generates $\cup$, `$\lor$` or `$\vee$` generates $\lor$, `$\Box$` or `$\square$` generates $\Box$, and `$\oplus$` generates $\oplus$. For extra, `$\div$` generates $\div$. Hope this makes things easier :)

Comment: Thx..for the Mathjax tip

Comment: Whoops, you'd want to generate `$\otimes$` to make $\otimes$, not `$o\plus$`. My bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's:

> ```
>  625 / 25 = 25
>    -    -    +
>  225 / 15 = 15
>    =    =    =
>  400 / 10 = 40
> ```

because:

> $\square$ is either $0,1,5,6$, it can't be $0$ from line 2, and therefore the sum involves either $21,31,15,25,16,26$, and only $21$ and $15$ fit the pattern. However $\square=1$ implies $\otimes=2$, and this is obviously false.

Comment: $\cap$, $\Delta$, and $\square$ are trivial to solve, since there's only one solution to BC*BC=ABC. Then $\cup$ is the only digit to solve in row 2.